# button with icon and title

Tags: blackberry, button, labelfield, bitmapfield

in my screen , i want to create/add button with an icon and under this icon i want to write the title of this button

[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDjSl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `Field`.

For instance, [here is an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912223/image-button-in-blackberry) of what to do. Your bitmap could alreay contain a label, or to have a `String` label freely "assignable" to this button you can extend that example (by adding the code to draw the label in `paint(Graphics graphics)`, check the API of `Graphics` - it is possible to write a text on it).