# Can a BlackBerry application have an image button?

Tags: blackberry, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image Button in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912223/image-button-in-blackberry)

Is there a way to have a picture be a button in blackberry? Trying to write a matching game.

Ted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912223/image-button-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code may help you:

public class ImageButtonFieldTest extends Field {

```
private Bitmap image;
private Bitmap selectedImage;
private int height;
private int width;

public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image, Bitmap selectedImage) {
    this.image = image;
    this.selectedImage = selectedImage;
    this.height = image.getHeight();
    this.width = image.getWidth();
}

protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {  
    setExtent(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

    // Draw img             
    if (isFocus()) {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, selectedImage, 0, 0);
    } else {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, image, 0, 0);
    }
}

public boolean isFocusable() {
    return true;
}

protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {        // Don't draw the default focus  
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
    invalidate();
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    invalidate();
}
```

}