# Blackberry development UI

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

[image: Open Heavens UI]

I am new to Blackberry dev, I want to port my android app to BB, but I found out it wont be possible for BB 7 Dev. So I've decided to create a simple app. However, I am having problems with the mainscreen, I do not know how to invoke the bitmapbuttons layout at app startup in the emulator. Any tutorials will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

GridFieldManager will do this sort of layout for you, but I have problems using it, so I always end up using the TablelayoutManager code that you can find in this article:

[Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299)

You will want to put images that act as Buttons in the layout.  There is no BB supplied class to do this, but plenty of samples if you search using a term like "image button", for example this one:

[image-button-in-blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912223/image-button-in-blackberry)